# Regex for finding substring

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have the following string "a b c".
With regex I want to find the substring " b" (please mind the space before the letter b).

When I do `[ b]`, it only find the space before b, but not the letter itself.
When I do `[ b]+`, it find b, but also the spaces before and after b. Same applies even for nonsense like`[   bbbbb   ]+`.

What is the right expression for finding only " b"?

PS: I tested my regex here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: `"a b c".match(/\sb/)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `( b)` to match for the space and b together (Note the parenthesis are optional depending if you are trying to match for it)

See this [**Regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vW5oT8/1) example.

Also, when you use `[ b]` it matches for a single character in the list (in this case a space and `b`) so it does not look to see if they are consecutive.

Edit: If you are looking to match a non-whitespace character instead of just a space, you can use `\sb` where `\s` is the token for a non-whitespace character.

Comment: beat me to it, yup this is the answer.

Comment: ...or even simply the regex ` b`. The parentheses are probably redundant.

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately I am unsure how to start a code block with a space because SO removes it, so I just added a comment to my answer.

Comment: `\s` is the token for a whitespace character, `\S` is for a non-whitespace character.